# OMP error Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use a software for genetic analysis. In the Linux system it works normal. However, I am curious about the bash for windows. And when I running my analysis the following error appears:

```
OMP: Error #100: Fatal system error detected.
OMP: System error #22: Invalid argument
forrtl: error (76): Abort trap signal
```

Please, anyone have any idea what can be and how to solve?

Comment: The code isn't compatible with windows subsystem; you'll need to talk to the software provider.

Comment: Is that Bash on Ubuntu on Windows or just Bash on Windows?

Comment: Yes, is "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows".

Comment: But, Mr. Harris is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It [is a known bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/785) in WSL with programs linked against Intel's MKL library. Solution is to `export KMP_AFFINITY=disabled` before running the program.

Answer (score 1):

I met similar problem. The solution for my case is to install `nomkl`.

```
conda install nomkl
```

I found this solution ([Here](https://www.scivision.co/anaconda-python-with-windows-subsystem-for-linux/))